# JSFiddle does not manage click events inside a function

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

I have a very simple JSFiddle

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="myBtn" onclick="foo()">
```

**JS**

```
function foo(){
    console.log('click');

  $("#myBtn").click(function(event) {
    console.log('click2');
  });

    console.log('click3');

}
```

Here's the link: https://jsfiddle.net/mdvyo481/

I've already loaded the script in *No Wrap - Head* mode. Strangely, when I click on the button, `click` and `click3` are printed in console but `click2` is not printed. If I click on it again, I get 2 prints of `click2`.

Looks like `event` is not properly managed in the fiddle. Is there a way to fix?

Comment: Nothing to do with JSFiddle, your code is wrong. It will behave exactly the same way in a browser.

Comment: To be more constructive, your event handler `foo` directly logs `click` and `click3`, and inbetween simply adds *another* `click` handler, which will log `click2`. So you won't see that until the next time you click it. And each subsequent click will add another handler, therefore `click2` will get logged more and more times. Basically, you should never add event listeners (for the same event) inside an event handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct behaviour. The reason this happens is because you bind the event `click` when you call the `foo` function. The first time you call `foo` you bind the event, the second time you bind it again and so on. Binding an event doesn't remove the previous bind, so if you click `submit` 10 times, you will bind 10 different `click` eventhandlers, all doing the same thing and you'll receive 'click2' 10 times in the console.

Answer (score 1):

Either add a click handler on your button using jquery or by using the onclick attribute, not both.

I've provided two examples to illustrate this:

```js
function foo(element) {
  console.log(element.id + ' was clicked <- onclick attribute handler')
}


$("#myBtn").click(function(event) {
  console.log(event.target.id + ' was  clicked, <- jQuery handler')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="myBtn" onclick="foo(this)">
```

Reason for your example not working is that you are setting the jquery click handler only after calling `foo()`, so it will not also trigger.